# How to Keyup Function use with in Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".main_calculations").delegate( '#advance_payment', '#discount', "keyup", function()
```

This function is not working. Does anyone know how to do that?

```js
function totalbal() {
  var tot = 0;
  $("#total").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot = parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });

  console.log(tot);

  $(".main_calculations").delegate('#advance_payment', '#discount', "keyup", function() {
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("advance_payment").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("discount").value);
    // to make sure that they are numbers

    if (!total) {
      total = 0;
    }

    if (!val2) {
      val2 = 0;
    }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("total_balance");
    ansD.value = tot - (total - val2);
  });
}
```

Comment: Firstly, that's not what the syntax of [`delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate) should look like, secondly it was deprecated a long time and you shouldn't be using it. Use [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Answer (score 0):

problem in the syntax

```
 $(".main_calculations").delegate('#advance_payment', '#discount', "keyup", function() {
```

it should be as `.delegate( selector, eventType, handler )`

```
 $(".main_calculations").delegate( '#advance_payment, #discount', "keyup",  function() {
```

**So as per all suggestion use**

```
 $(".main_calculations").on("keyup", '#advance_payment, #discount', function() {
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been **deprecated**. It was superseded by the **.on()** method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged

Comment: Ok let me check your suggestion.

Comment: DONE bro. thanks man. this one is working.
 $(".main_calculations").delegate("keyup", '#advance_payment, #discount',  function()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function totalbal() {
    var tot = 0;
    $("#total").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
    tot = parseFloat(this.value);
    }
    });

    console.log(tot);

    $(".main_calculations").delegate('#advance_payment,#discount', "keyup", 
   function() {
   var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("advance_payment").value);
   var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("discount").value);
   // to make sure that they are numbers

   if (!total) {
  total = 0;
   }

   if (!val2) {
    val2 = 0;
   }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("total_balance");
    ansD.value = tot - (total - val2);
    });
    }
```